# Saving Blender Macro to file

Tags: scripting, add-on

I have used the Macro Recorder (http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Development/Macros_Recorder) to record some actions in Blender.

Does anybody know how I can save the macro to a file so that I can use it again even after having closed Blender?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recorded macros are stored as small text blocks in the *Text Editor* as *macro*, Blender will incrementally add a numeric constant to these so take care to rename before saving. To execute the macro again, execute them from there.

Comment: Could you please add more info on where I find the Text Editor and how I can load it to another blender project?

Comment: @JohannHesters After saving the macro, look in the botton left corner of your screen, you will see an icon with 2 opposite arrows, click that and look for the text editor, or temporarily change your screen layout from Default to Scripting.